# App crashes after setting to Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Tags: android

My app will start if I don't take away the title bar but when I do it crashes as soon as it starts.

This is the code I have so far.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.v1.solitare"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">


        <activity
            android:name="com.v1.solitare.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help in any way possible. I just picked up Android coding with Eclipse today and I'm very new at it.

Edit: I think I found the LogCat Errors for it:

```
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.v1.solitare/com.v1.solitare.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at com.v1.solitare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
04-02 22:06:28.986: E/AndroidRuntime(28352):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding so bad but how can I get that? I see it on the tab but its constantly scrolling.

Comment: Clear logcat, run your app again and copy only red text appeared in your logcat related to your app and paste it in above question, format it by `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: Added the errors that showed up after running the application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` assumes you are using an `ActionBar`, while `Theme.NoTitleBar` themes remove the ActionBar (as that is part of the title bar on newer devices and `ActionBarActivity` assumes you are using a `Theme.AppCompat` theme which controls styling for the ActionBar).

Change your activity to extend `FragmentActivity` if you are okay with not having an Action Bar, although as per the [Android design docs](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) is a critical component for making your app feel like an Android app (although some would say that games are granted more leeway).

Comment: I believe you are right I will try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Updated my answer given the logcat you posted - ActionBarActivity requires a `Theme.AppCompat` theme (as only those style the action bar that `ActionBarActivity` provides). You can use `FragmentActivity` in its place if you don't want an action bar and then you can continue to use `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: That worked perfectly! And I just dont like the giant line at the top of the screen. It interferes with the outline of everything